# does CAST cut a string from the beggining always?

Tags: sql, string, postgresql, casting, varchar

Hi I was using the CAST function in PostgreSQL with a column called dayhour of type BIGINT which contains TIMESTAMPS in the format YYYYMMDDHH (ex 2020051912)

So, actually I only need the YYYYMMDD of that field (ex 20200519) in varchar type for example.

Does `CAST(dayhour AS VARCHAR(8))` cut the date and hour and takes only 'YYYYMMDD' always?

Do you know a better way to accomplish that?

Edit: I know I could use the SUBSTRING function also, but wanted to know if this is as safe as using SUBSTRING function...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not to try it yourself? [I did it for you.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=7f5b60e85f446f07a29d8ed0bfb6875c)

Seems it's possible, though it is little bit weird way how to do substring...

Even to the timestamp the string can be cast.

```
select cast(2020051912::bigint as varchar(8));
select cast('2020051912' as varchar(8));
select cast(2020051912::bigint as varchar(8))::timestamp;
```

Comment: Yeah I tried and it substring the date as I want, just wanted to be sure about this way. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use `cast()`.  I think that `left()` is clearer in intent:

```
select left(dayhour::text, 6)
```

Or, because this is a number:

```
select floor(dayhour / 100)
```

(The `floor()` is redundant because Postgres does integer division, but I like to be careful.)

I would encourage you to use proper `date` values.  Postgres can easily convert this to a date:

```
select left(dayhour::text, 6)::date
```

Or, store the value as a `timestamp` and use a `check` constraint to be sure that it is exactly an hour:

```
check (dayhour = date_trunc('hour', dayhour))
```

You can add a computed column to represent this as a bigint:

```
alter table t add column day_hour_bigint bigint generated always as 
    (to_char(dayhour, 'YYYYMMDDHH24')::bigint)
```